# AEM 6:: Dispatcher entry for /bin/<path>

Tags: apache, aem

Currently I am getting a 404 on the Sling Servlet that is mapped to the path /bin/uhc/myuhcauthenticationhandler. My best guess is it is being blocked on the dispatcher.Also this servlet takes care of POST requests only. What entry can I do in the dispatcher to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests that the Dispatcher accepts / denies are configured in the [Filters](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html#par_134_32_0009) section of the **dipatcher.any** file (unless and otherwise configured with a different name during installation).

Rules defined to deny a request pattern would send a 404 response.

Use the below filter at the bottom of the filters list so that the other rules do not override this.

`/0999 { /type "allow" /method "POST" /url "/bin/uhc/myuhcauthenticationhandler*" }`

Check [this adobe documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html) to know more about configuring the dispatcher.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the fast response. Appreciate it. I was also wondering if it is possible to somehow be able to test it in local along with Siteminder response. Since, I don't have the admin rights to the server most of the times I have to just wait and see if everything is working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: You can test it in local in case you have the complete set up available i.e., a web server in which the dispatcher module is installed and configured to the AEM instance running in your machine.

Comment: Yeah I have web server and dispatcher configured. But since the redirection happens through Siteminder. I am not sure how do I make it happen.